# How to change the font size in my textview

Tags: objective-c

I am using a textview in which I have passed an array of objects. In that array I have taken a list of messages that would be passed to the textview, but I have changed the size of textview font so. give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my application.

Below my code in that I have apply the UIFont but that is not use in font.

```
msgtxtView.text=selectedmsg;
[msgtxtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10]]
```

`selectedmsg` is array of object in that message list that would be pass to textview's object but output font size and arialfont not work give any.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
msgtxtView.text=selectedmsg;
[msgtxtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at his example how to add text from array and change size (You changing size correctly):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"message1", @"message2", @"message3", @"message4", @"message5", nil];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    msgtxtView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\n",msgtxtView.text,[array objectAtIndex:i]];
}

[msgtxtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10]];
```

Don't forget to **IBOutlet** msgtxtView.

Result:

[image]

And for example using this: `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:25]`:

[image]